# In bootstrap how to fit Image Automatically to All MobileDevice

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap css how does one fit an image or video automatically to all mobile devices based on its Resolution.

Answer (score 1):

For images, use Bootstrap's [Responsive Images](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) functionality. For video or embedded content, use Bootstrap's [Responsive Embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) to preserve the aspect ratio.

Example ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pymw1sqf/)):

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/%C3%84lvkarleby_June_2013.jpg/800px-%C3%84lvkarleby_June_2013.jpg" class="img-responsive">

<hr>

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="responsive-embed"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SirRu8mf3II" >
    </iframe>
</div>
```